# How can I add processing of text blocks before outputting them on site?

Tags: 8

I have a library, that formats text for better readability. I want to put processing of text blocks and strings before outputting them on site, Where and how to do this?

The processor a very simple:

```
require_once("EMT.php");

$typograph = new EMTypograph();

$typograph->set_text($contentof_text_block);

$contentof_text_block = $typograph->apply();
```

Drupal 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement a text filter. Here is an example, FilterHtml, from core: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!filter!src!Plugin!Filter!FilterHtml.php/8

Here is one that I made: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mathjax/tree/src/Plugin/Filter/MathjaxFilter.php